# A popup in an Modal window to replace JS confirm and alert - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I am working on a ASP.NET website that needs popups in a modal window similar to JS confirm and alert. How would I do this on client and/or server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any specific library?  Many popular libraries have this built in or available as plugins

[jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

[dijit.dialog](http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dijit_Dialog_Basic) (Dojo)

[MochaUI](http://mochaui.com/docs/files/Window/Modal-js.html) (Mootools)

Comment: Are you not using a library *yet* or are you unable to use a library at all.  I would suggest that you look into one to help mitigate cross-browser compatibility issues.

Comment: I am unable to the library. Is ajax modal control a good fit?

Answer (score 0):

Anything like this..

windowHandle = window.open("*.html", ID, "modal,toolbar=false,location=false,directories=false,status=false,menubar=false,scrollbars=no,resizable=no);

windowHandle.focus();